# Spark: best practice to use a web-service from a spark app

Tags: web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to add some geographical information to a dataframe. i.a. for thousands of row, I want to call a web-service, with latitude and longitude as parameter, the WS returning the value of a new field. I should use a UDF to do it.

However, I feel there will be a big performance issue; the web-service may be over-used and slow-down the whole application.

Are there best practices regarding the use of a WS from a spark-application?